# Company page says I have pending changes - but I don't?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Company page click edit page...went to the **basic info** tab and didn't change a single thing.  If I try to tab over to something else like "statement 1" it errors saying that:

**You have pending changes, please cancel or save ->**

I have not made any changes...this error just happens whenever you click the **basic info** tab and try to tab over to another tab.

[image]

Also how do we change a Company name?  I don't see an option for that...